# Как игнорировать числа в input name=name[123]?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Мне нужно обработать через **JQuery** инпуты, но в одном из инпутов у меня стоят ID постов WordPress:

```
  $my_list = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'category' => $id = 25,
  ));

  echo '<div class="select_obj">';

  foreach ($my_list as $key => $my_list) {
    echo '<span><input type="checkbox" name="chek_list[' . $my_list->ID . ']">' . $my_list->post_title . '<br/><input type="date" id="date" name="chek_date[' . $my_list->ID . ']"></span><br/>';
  }

  echo '</div>';
```

Как я могу через **JQuery** смогу игнорировать числа в []?

Comment: Попробуй лучше использовать шаблонизатор вместо подобной генерации html, например: twig.

Comment: @kvxmmu зачем это нужно?

Comment: Мне просто нужно узнать выбран или нет тот или иной name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для такой ситуации можете использовать:

```
$("input[name^='chek_list']").val();
```

Получите значение input, name которого начинается с chek_list, а далее в имени может идти любой ID. Таким образом при такой выборке id постов указывать не нужно.

Comment: Большое спасибо)